# Flex with a taller left column and right column that fills with smaller items

Tags: flexbox

[image: My Layout]

I have a layout with 2 columns.  The content flows from left to right and then onto a new row.  Is there a way to flow from left to right, but only make a new row if there is not enough space on the right?

The attached image is the current  output. As you can see the first two items sit next to each other, but then there is a huge space in the right-hand column.  I would like for the other items to fill the right hand space if the right hand space  is less height than the left hand block.

I've tried setting `align-self: flex-start;` so the right-hand items don't grow. But only one will ever fit there.  My solution at the moment is two flex columns of 47% and then move all the items into that containing `<div>`.

I thought this was achievable by Flex alone without the additional `<div>` if they were all the right height.

**CSS**

```
.flex-parent {

    display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -moz-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
        -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-rendering: optimizespeed;
    }

    .flex-child {
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -moz-box-flex: 0;
        box-flex: 0;
        -webkit-flex: 0 47%;
        -moz-flex: 0 47%;
        -ms-flex: 0 47%;
        flex: 0 47%;
        width: 47%;
        align-self: flex-start;
    }
    .flex-spacer {
            -webkit-box-flex: 0;
            -moz-box-flex: 0;
            box-flex: 0;
            -webkit-flex: 0 6%;
            -moz-flex: 0 6%;
            -ms-flex: 0 6%;
            flex: 0 6%;
            width: 6%;
            align-self: flex-start;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-child">
      Stuff & Ting
  </div>
  <div class="flex-spacer">

  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
      Stuff & Ting
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
      Stuff & Ting
  </div>
  <div class="flex-spacer">

  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
      Stuff & Ting
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your post is a bit confusing. Read it twice and still don't know exactly what you're trying to do. The attached image, is it showing a problem or is what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I edited it, maybe that helps.  The image is the current result. I'm on my phone perhaps I'll try to create another image to show what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achievable by using some CSS for `nth-child` and by using `Flex: columns`

I found this out from this website: https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/masonry-with-css/

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: column wrap;
```

will ensure they go into column order.

`nth-child(-n+6){ order: 2; }` will select the first 6

`first-child{ order: 1;}` resets the first one

At that point they will flow neatly and only wrap after the space has been filled in.